# Error connecting to Postgres database container

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring with Java and docker and I've been using this series of tutorials online.
In this particular tutorial that I'm currently studying, the code compiles without errors and the logs look fine but I can't seem to connect to the database.

The error that I have is `The connection attempt failed. db`

Here is the repository with the code that should be working fine:

https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/docker-modules/docker-spring-boot-postgres

When I run docker-compose up the code compiles normally, the containers are created but when I use dbeaver to connect the database I get the error.

[printscreen of dbeaver error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL5RC.png)

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I think the host should probably be localhost or something like that?

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: in the docker-compose the property SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL is like this:
`SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/compose-postgres`

So the host should be `bd` (the postgres container)... at least that's what makes sense to me

Comment: Hi Senjhu. That is the hostname within the docker network. I don't think 'db' is exposed outside, where you are running dbeaver.

Comment: In addition to what @toolkit said, we also need to forward the port of the container where the postgres process is listening (`5432`) tot he host and connect dbeaver through the host port. See the [relevant `docker` documentation (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to access the postgres service running in a container from the docker host. To achieve this, the solution is twofold:

- export the container-port on which the postgres process is listening (`5432`) to the docker host, and
- connect dbeaver to this port

#### Export the container-port to the docker host

We can achieve this through the `ports` keyword in the `docker-compose.yml`. See [the relevant `docs.docker.io` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) for detail. In the example below, I chose to map the host-port `15432` to the container-port `5432`. Depending on what ports are used on the machine, you may want to change the host-port

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  ...   
  db:
    ...
    ports:
      - '15432:5432'
```

#### Connect dbeaver to the right host and port

Name resolution in a docker network only works for containers in that network. So the host cannot resovlve container-names from the network. Luckly, in the first step we mapped the host-port `15432` to the container-port `5432`. Thus, all data sent to `15432` of the local host will be passed along to the container port `5432`. Thus, we should configure dbeaver to connect to `locahost`, port `15432`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new using docker and spent quite a few hours trying to figure this out